# Web app button showing in Android but not iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, button

Have a web app which has a button that is working fine in Android but not showing at all across multiple iOS devices on Safari or Chrome.
For readability I've excluded much of the code except the button code, in a hope it's something simple with this.  Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<style>
.button {
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: fixed;
            
            margin: 0 auto;
            
            cursor: pointer;
            
            
        }

        .button1 {background-color: darkblue;}
</style>

<button class="button button1" id="unmuteButton">UNMUTE</button>

<canvas id="camerafeed"></canvas>
```

And the JS:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("unmuteButton");

btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    if(btn.innerText === "UNMUTE"){
        btn.innerText = "MUTE"
        depthkit.video.muted = false
    }else{
        btn.innerText= "UNMUTE";
        depthkit.video.muted = 'muted'
    }
})
```

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: none;` might be the one making difference

Comment: ah sorry that was me experimenting and was not supposed to be in there.  I have removed it from the code in question, and the question still stands.

Comment: So, from What I can read, I think your button is not visible only on your web app.
but does it display on the web instead?

Comment: Maybe I am using the term webapp incorrectly.  It is a WebAR experience which you open with a QR code (URL) and then access within your browser on your phone.  The button is visible on Android in chrome, but absent on iPhones on Safari or Chrome.  The button is supposed to appear over the camera feed (as you can see above, the canvas being the feed)